# How to use proxy in terminal

Tags: terminal, network, proxy, git

Department of Telelcom (India) just blocked some sites in India.

But, only Government-based ISPs block access those sites. Other ISPs still have these sites working. One of those sites is Github and I want to use Github.

How can I apply proxy settings so they work for git sessions to Github in a Terminal?

(Note: I saw this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal) for doing this in Linux but I guess OS X is little different from Ubuntu?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the StackOverflow Q&A entitled "[Getting git to work with a proxy server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)":

> Command to use :
>
> ```
> git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
> git config --global https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
> ```
>
> - change proxyuser by your proxy user
> - change proxypwd by your prxy password
> - change proxy.server.com by proxy server url
> - change 8080 by proxy port
>
> If you decide at any time to reset this proxy and work without (no
>   proxy):
>
> Commands to use:
>
> ```
> git config --global --unset http.proxy
> git config --global --unset https.proxy
> ```

Git also respects the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables.